# Easy way to create cloudless mosaic

Tags: remote-sensing, sentinel-2, mosaic, cloud-cover

Is there an easy way (or easy access database) to create cloudless mosaics for a country (e.g. Germany) from Sentinel-2 data?

I found this ressource: https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-s2-l2a-mosaic-120/

But I am not really sure how to use aws to download it. Is there any other way?

Comment: That data appears to have resampled to 120 m pixel size. Is that what you want?

Comment: it would be ok yes:)

Comment: There is an official S2GM service but it feels complicated https://usermanual.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/.